# mailto with no default email client

Tags: html, mailto

A friend has developed a corporate website which has a mailto link as the 'contact us' link.  The problem is that if windows has no default email client it does not work, there isn't even an error message.  I was going to suggest changing it to a link through to a contact page with perhaps an email form but can anyone suggest anything quicker/simpler?

```
mailto:email@company.com?subject= enquiry
```

Cheers,
Cap

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't anything quicker. You can, however, make sure the link text is the email address to facilitiate copy/paste into a webmail client.

Answer (score 0):

If the link text is the email address it is inconvenient to double click to select and then copy (rather then dragging from first to last letter). 
When a specific subjectline is needed, you can say so, but since the mailto already has prefilled fields, you should also say so (and add it to the title of the email link), to avoid the users with a webclient to first copy the subjectline and then click the mailto link.

> Send us an [email (pre-composed)](http://email)  at mail@example.tld, with subject 'enquiry'